# Seem /etc/exports can only export one directoy

Tags: nfs

on the nfsserver (called ubuntu) the `/etc/exports contains`

```
/media/ext 192.160.1.0/24(rw)
/home/file 192.160.1.0/24(rw)
```

On the client machine `sudo mount -t nfs ubuntu:/home/file /mnt` was executed, however when executed `ls /mnt`, the contents were from `/media/ext`.

Although only one nfs mount was executed, on the server `/var/lib/nfs/rmtab` contains

```
192.160.1.103:/media/ext:0x00000001
192.160.1.103:/home/file:0x00000001
```

why was `ubuntu:/media/ext` was mounted instead of `ubuntu:/home/file`?

If the order in `/etc/exports` reverse, as

```
192.160.1.103:/media/file:0x00000001
192.160.1.103:/home/ext:0x00000001
```

then `/media/file` was mounted.
It seem the exportfs only export the first entry

Please help
Thanks

Comment: Did you restart your NFS server after editing the `/etc/exports`? Also try `showmount -e ubuntu` on your client.

Comment: yes I did restart nfs server.
You mean showmout on the server ?
showmount -e
Export list for ubuntu:
/home/file                      192.160.1.0/24
/media/ext                      192.160.1.0/24

Comment: You should be able to execute `showmount` on the client to see if the mounts are seen from there too.

Comment: Hi  on the client executing showmout  clnt_create: RPC: Program not registered  showmount -e ubuntu  Export list for ubuntu:  /home/file 192.160.1.0/24  /media/ext 192.160.1.0/24.  Thanks